# How to get the related image from Firebase storage in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage, stream-builder

I'm trying to build a list of widgets that are displayed using streambuilder for each entry in my cloud firestore. Here's the code:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ProperHomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {


  @override
  _ProperHomeScreenState createState() => _ProperHomeScreenState();
}

class _ProperHomeScreenState extends State<ProperHomeScreen> {
  final _firestore = Firestore.instance;
  String _downloadURL;
  StorageReference _reference = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }


  void postsStream() async {
    await for (var snapshot in _firestore.collection('posts').snapshots()) {
      for (var post in snapshot.documents) {
        print(post.data);
      }
    }
  }

  testFunction(postImage) async {

      print('Here\'s the postImage data from test function: $postImage');
      String downloadAddress = await _reference.child(postImage).getDownloadURL();
      setState(() {
        _downloadURL = downloadAddress;
      });
      print('THIS IS THE DOWNLOAD URL FROM THE TEST FUNCTION! ::: $_downloadURL');

    }

   


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[

            StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot> (
              stream: _firestore.collection('posts').snapshots(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if(!snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                    ),
                  );
                }
                  final posts = snapshot.data.documents;
                  List<Widget> postWidgets = [];
                  for (var post in posts)  {
                    final postText = post.data['questionOne'];
                    final postSender = post.data['email'];
                    final postImage = post.data['filePath'];

                    testFunction(postImage);

                    print('THIS IS THE DOWNLOAD ADDRESS : $_downloadURL');


                    final postWidget = Container(
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text('$postText from $postSender with image : $postImage'),
                          Image.network('$_downloadURL'),
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                    postWidgets.add(postWidget);
                  }
                  return Column(
                    children: postWidgets,
                  );

              },
            ),

          ],
        ),
      );
  }

}
```

In the console, it is printing urls fine, but the problem I have is that it keeps running the testFunction() continuously until I stop main.dart.

I'm trying to show a different image for each post.

Essentially, I am saving data in cloud firestore and saving images in firebase storage. I'm storing the file name of the image in cloud firestore so that I can access it.

Here's a sample of how I'm saving a post in firestore:

```
void submitPostSection() {
    DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    _firestore.collection('posts').add({
      'email': loggedInUser.email,
      'date': now,
      'questionOne': widget.questionOne, //this is a simple string. Example data: 'Here is the latest post today 31st July 2020'
      'filePath' : _filePath, // this is just the image name that its saved as in firebase storage. datatype for this is string. here's an example of the data: 'myimage2.jpg'
    });
  }
```

I think the problem is because the method keeps getting called and setting state of _downloadURL. I'm not really sure the best way to go about this.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my problem. I deleted the testFunction() and just saved the actual imageURL inside the cloud firestore document. Then I can access it really easily by adding the following line:

`final postImageUrl = post.data['imageURL'];`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that inside `testFunction()` you are calling `setState()` which will keep calling the `build()` method, you can do the following:

```
  List<String> listOfUrl = [];
  for (var post in posts)  {
    final postText = post.data['questionOne'];
    final postSender = post.data['email'];
    final postImage = post.data['filePath'];
    String downloadAddress = await _reference.child(postImage).getDownloadURL();
    listOfUrl.add(downloadAddress);
   }
ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: listOfUrl.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
         return Card(
           child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
             children: <Widget>[
              Image.network(listOfUrl[index]),
                 ],
                ),
              );
           });
```

add the urls inside a list and then use a listview to display them.

Comment: Hi Peter, Thank you very much for your response. I tried the code you suggested, but error messages keep getting displayed: error: The await expression can only be used in an async function. Any ideas?